# How to send email in Android ?

Tags: android, email

How does one send a simple email message, in code, on Android?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Intent sendIntent;

sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Subject");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Test Text");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + fileName));
sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send Mail"));
```

Comment: It needs : sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

Answer (score 4):

Check out the code at [anddev.org](http://www.anddev.org/email_send_intent_intentchooser-t3295.html) for how to do it using intents.

Comment: Thanx Chris Thompson i posted the code that works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the User interface for sending mails, check this link:  [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app/2033124#2033124)