# Need native email application android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send email in Android ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585556/how-to-send-email-in-android)

How to embeded the native email application within android .In that i need 3 buttons SEND,SAVE AS DRAFT,DISCARD with default functionality and TO also auto populate email adresses.Please help me.

```
Intent mailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Intent mailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "To");
            mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject");
            mailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mailText.toString());
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Compose Mail"));
```

it i take this code the Send button appeares beside Body.but I need the buttons(3)  below the Body(Compose).![alt text][1]

But I need like this

![alt text][2]

Comment: You are trying to open the email program Compose Window and have the fields auto pre-populated, correct?

Comment: iam getting Send button only.that too sided by Body text.but I need these 3 buttons below the body text.I don't have much exp on this please help me out