# How to add an image in email body

Tags: android, image, email, email-attachments

I want to add an image in email body.
I don't want to attach an image to the email, but add an image in the email body.

How to do this?

I'm using this.

```
"<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,"+convertFileTOByteEncrypt()+"\">"
```

or

```
  "<img src=\"http://images.anandtech.com/doci/3982/HTCSurround-0134.jpg\">"
```

Then image is displayed like this.

[image]

Comment: Android program? Sending to an Android? What exactly do you want?

Comment: I think you're probably out of luck on this one, as support differs between mail clients... What about using plain old attachments and html mail?

Comment: Did anyone resolve it? :) I'm facing with the same problem [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086975/how-to-send-email-with-image-icon-displayed-in-body-in-android

Comment: @SteveLuck still not any solution for this ..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to do this with Intents.

The reason why for example bold text is displayed in the EditText and not an Image is that [StyleSplan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan.html) is implementing [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) whereas [ImageSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html) does not. So when the Intent.EXTRA_TEXT is retrieved in the new Activity the ImageSpan will fail to unparcel and therefor not be part of the style appended to the EditText.

Using other methods where you don't pass the data with the Intent is unfortunately not possible here as you're not in control of the receiving Activity.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264622/android-multiple-email-attachment-using-intent-question).

It seems that you can use:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

where `uri` is a file path `URI`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. But it is attache image and i want add image in email body.. anyother code for add image in email body..

Comment: From what I read, you can do this but most email clients won't show the image. I think you're better off using attachments or using an html link in your message body.

Comment: Yes, You are right. But i must add image in email body as per client requirement.

Comment: ahh. Well I think the IMAGEDATA method or multipart-data is your best bet.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create an email with HTML body and embedded image: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1761/embedding-images-in-email/

To send email in Android follow this recipe: [How to send email in Android ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585556/how-to-send-email-in-android/3585701#3585701)

Comment: The default email client and gmail client do not support rich HTML email. So you can not embed images, make text bold, etc..

Comment: so, anyother way to embed images...?