# how to send image in email body via Android application

Tags: android

i have to sent image via my application in mail body.
but i am unable to see that image in mail editor. it only shows rectangular box with written "OBJ" inside.
thanx.

I am using the following code.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);                                                                             
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
    "Product:"+ProductComparisonActivity.s_title);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Title:
    "+ProductComparisonActivity.s_title+"\n"+"Description:
    "+ProductComparisonActivity.s_des+"\n"+"\n"+"Max Price:
    "+ProductComparisonActivity.s_max+"\n"+"Min Price:
    "+ProductComparisonActivity.s_min+"\n");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<img src="+"\""+ProductComparisonActivity.image_med+";base64,#IMAGEDATA#"+"\">",imgGetter,null));
// emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, ProductComparisonActivity.prod_bmp);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show an image in the email body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201682/how-to-show-an-image-in-the-email-body)

Comment: Bro, were you able to accomplish this? I am in a similar need.. Many have suggested over other similar posts to set the mime type to html and embed an tag to an external image somewhere like <img src="http://imgur.com/myimage.png"></img> .. You have tried the same but as mentioned by you, it doesn't help.. So, should we consider it as a limitation? :O

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't think it is possible.