# How to attach Bitmap to email android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a bitmap that I have saved in the external storage. I already have a method that loads and returns the bitmap. My question is, how do I attach this image to an email Intent.

Note: I know how to start the email intent, I simply need to know how to attach the bitmap. Thanks.

This is how I am saving the pic:

```
private void savePicture(String filename, Bitmap b, Context ctx) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream out;
        out = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, out);
        if (b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, out) == true)
            out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201682/how-to-show-an-image-in-the-email-body

Comment: I need to attach the file rather than in the body. thanks for the reply anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this for Attach Image with Email

**Fetch Image From SdCard**

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();     
File file = new File(path,"YourImageName.JPEG");
Uri pngUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

**Email Intent**

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngUri);
```

Comment: this is attaching the picture, but my picture is blank( no picture) why is this?

Comment: See my updated code... I think the file path is incorrect, but I don't know what the file path is