# how to send E-mail html content with images in mail body using android

Tags: android

how to send E-mail html content with images in mail body using android

My code :

```
 final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
 emailIntent.setType("text/html");
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"to");
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC,"cc");
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject");
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(body));

this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose your email program"));
```

But mail body not display some html contains and images.

Please Help me.

Advance Thanks.

Comment: are you sending images in `<img>` tag? can you post some snippet of your `body` content which you are sending.

Comment: my body contence in get json data like

Comment: post your body json data here

Comment: <html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0">

                    <map name="top_map" id="top_map"></map>  

<table width="192" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" > 
        <tr>
       
        <td valign="top" colspan="3">
        <img alt="" src="http://pro.wrapmail.com/wraps/custom/images\user\6903_1_350.jpg" border="0" usemap="#top_map"/></td></tr><tr>......

Comment: but mail body display  ￼

￼￼￼￼￼ ￼Endangered Runaway: SASY ARULONG (HI)12/29/2012 12:00:00 PM ￼

Comment: is my solution helpful to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try with this :**

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
           .append(body).toString()));
```

**Instead of :**

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(body));
```

**EDIT :**

Here is my test and it is working well.

```
       String body = "<html><body><h1>this is h1</h1><b>wel come to html formet</b></body></html>";

       final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
       shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The Subject");
       shareIntent.putExtra(
       Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
       Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
           .append(body).toString())
       );
       startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Thanks.

Comment: i try to simple html contence display like <html><body><h1>this is h1</h1><b>wel come to html formet</b></body></html> but get my json data it not display.

Comment: thanks pratik i try this code complite work but me add image that not display .

Comment: String body = "<html><body><h1>this is h1</h1><img src='http://www.mindinventory.com/images/logo.gif'/></body></html>";

         final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
         shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The Subject");
         shareIntent.putExtra(
         Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder().append(body).toString()));
         startActivity(shareIntent);

Comment: @kailash refer this thread. [ http://stackoverflow.com/a/6476890/556975 ] .It is open issue with Android to send image with email body.

Comment: thanks pratik send image in using inten not posible but other way then give me example.....thanks

Comment: @kailash yes sure. I will look into this further. Till then if my effort is helpful to you somehow then you can accept my given solution. Thanks.