# How to send html content with image through android default email client?

Tags: android, email

[image: Image describing the requirement for android 2.2+ Devices]

How can we get inline images in default email client for android through Hypertext Markup Language (HTML) ?

Answer (score 4):

**You can not**. As default Email application's doesn't support `<img />` tag.

Because, [ImageSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html) doesn't implementing [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Hence its failed with **Intent's PUT_EXTRA**.

Its works only for basic tags, like, `<b>, <i>` ..etc

Look at [Sending html email in android using <table>, etc. - is there really no relatively built-in Intent way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787171/sending-html-email-in-android-using-table-etc-is-there-really-no-relativel) and [How to show an image in the email body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201682/how-to-show-an-image-in-the-email-body)

Answer (score 1):

String body ="`<html><body><table>...</table></body></html>`";

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body).toString());                    
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

Unfortunately, the `<table>` `,'img'` tag isn't supported. **Supported tags are actually more dependent on the email client you use to send the email - some of them are more finicky/restrictive than others**. Most of them use the super-basic formatting tags like `<b>, <i>, <h1>,` and so on, though.