# Exclude html tags in message with cordova social sharing plugin

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I'm able to load data dynamic to be shared on social media like whatsapp etc. But the problem is the message comes along with html tags like `<p>`, `<br>` etc.
Its there a way I could format the message so its sends it as is while maintaining the formatting of the message but not showing the html tags.

```
<button class="invite" data-role="none" onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share( $('#data').html())">Share Invite a Friend</button>
```

Comment: This link is useful for you. https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#email
and also
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15136538/3786343