# Send email intent with image in html body

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Is it possible to send an email, using an intent, with an image in the body. 
I'm using an image that is hosted...

```
public void sendEmail(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/html");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Image in body test");

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(getHtmlBody()));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
}

private String getHtmlBody() {
    String html = "<h1><img width=\"100\" src=\"http://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/30-impossibly-cute-puppies/impossibly-cute-puppy-8.jpg\">   Hello World </h1>";
    return html;
}
```

I am able to do this using javaMail but that sends the email automatically without the user being able to see anything so I'm hoping I can use intents.

Comment: Did you try it? If not, try it, see what happens.

Comment: Well, I tried it, it does seem to recognize HTML, but not so much `<img/>` tags. I'm looking to see if there is any way to get this to work.

Comment: Why are you using Html.fromHtml() ?

Comment: You have an absolute url for the src tag. In this way the image will never be included. But the receiver will see the image as the mail app will load the image from internet.

Comment: do you fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

There is [`EXTRA_HTML_TEXT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_HTML_TEXT) that allows you to supply HTML as alternative to the text in `EXTRA_TEXT`. However, there's no guarantee that the receiving app supports this extra (hence the requirement that `EXTRA_TEXT` must be present, too).

The code could look something like this:

```
public void sendEmail(View view){
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  intent.setType("text/plain");
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Image in body test");
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getTextBody());
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, getHtmlBody());

  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
}

private String getHtmlBody() {
  return "<h1><img width=\"100\" src=\"http://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/30-impossibly-cute-puppies/impossibly-cute-puppy-8.jpg\">"
      + getTextBody() + "</h1>";
}

private String getTextBody() {
  return "Hello world";
}
```

Apps that don't support HTML will simply use the text from `EXTRA_TEXT`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Arpit Garg in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136480/how-to-send-html-content-with-image-through-android-default-email-client)  shares that  and  tags do not work in most email clients, so unfortunately your code wont work. I just tested your code with the Gmail app and a few others and it pulled in a placeholder but not the actual image. what you can do though is add an image as an attachment.