# how to display image in mail on android

Tags: android, android-image

in my android app i need to take screen capture and share the captured screen in mail(captured screen to be shown mail).

i did screen capture by the following code:

```
view = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.screen);
......... 

View v1 = view.getRootView();

System.out.println("Root View : "+v1);

v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();

System.out.println("Bitmap : "+bm);

iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

this take the screen short and show the image in ImageView. i do not know  how to display the screen capture in mail and where the image is stored. please help me.

Log cat : i get the following

**08-01 12:40:40.640: INFO/System.out(3115): Bitmap : android.graphics.Bitmap@44f0c508**

Comment: what do you mean .. `bring screen capture in mail`?

Comment: save image to file and send as attachment :S ?

Comment: how to save it and i need to display in message part not as attachment.please help me.

Comment: it wont work ... as simple as that

Comment: for save image i get code from "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/android-bitmap-save-to-location". and tried that but image not stored properly.  i need in email body. please help me.

Comment: Look at following thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244472/how-add-image-in-email-body

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri U=Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/logo.png");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"sivafarshore@yahoo.com");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is email's message");
emailIntent.setType("image/png");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,U);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

Comment: for save image i get code from "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/android-bitmap-save-to-location". and tried that but image not stored properly. and your code show the image as attachment but i need in email body. please help me.