# Using HTML in a String

Tags: android, html, mvchtmlstring

In my application I have to use a some HTML stuff in a string. But HTML is not working as intended. I have to use that string (Text) to send as an email. The sequence I required of HTML is:

Title (in the center)

Image (in the center)

Description (left align)

and then this HTML string is passed to an email intent. But neither image is showing up in the email nor the title text is getting center align. This is how I am doing this all:

```
        Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
        it.setType("text/html");
        String title = title;
        String emailText = emailText;   
        it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
        it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(emailText));
        this.startActivity(it);
```

and this is how the emailText is being formed:

```
 emailText = "<p style= 'color:#000000; font:Georgia; font-size:18pt; text-align:center' align = 'center'><b>" + title +" </b></p>"
             +"<br/><br />"
             +"<img style=\"border:3px solid #173E8C\" src=\'" +imageUrl+"\' width=\"120\" height=\"90\"align=\"center\"/>"
             +"<br/><br/>"
             +"<p>" + description;
```

But I am unable to get the required result that I have mentioned right at the top, Any help is appreciated related to the issue. Thanks in advance..:-)

Comment: Try doing, this line `"<img style=\"border:3px solid #173E8C\" src=\'" +imageUrl+"\' width=\"120\" height=\"90\"align=\"center\"/>"` should look like this `"<img style='border:3px solid #173E8C' src='" +imageUrl+"' width='120' height='90'align='center'/>"`

Comment: I tried the same in first attempt...it did not worked..to confirm I have tried it again but no luck...

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the type of email through the function setType () :

```
it.setType("text/html");  // for HTML
it.setType("text/plain"); // for plain text
```

Comment: try this before Html.fromHtml() :  TextUtils.htmlEncode(emailText)

Comment: What is the intent of targeted email? AOSP email, Gmail or email client manufacturer (HTC, ...)?

Comment: It's Gmail...I have used Email client too...but it also did not show the image

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a image as email body in android through Intent.

Comment: image being sent is wrapped in an html string.

Comment: see the accepted answer in this link. You will get the reason. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244472/how-add-image-in-email-body

Comment: Yes I have gone through this thread...but isn't there any other way to do so..???? Or it's a clear straight "No"..????

Comment: yes, there is no possible ways. I have also tired, results in vain.

Comment: refer this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/J1PpmLQnTWI