# send email with image in android

Tags: android

I want email with image which is fatch from drowable in android I show bellow given link but same problem arise:
[How to add an image in email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244472/how-add-image-in-email-body)

and if I put

```
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml("<b>content</b>"+"<img src=\"data:"+getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smile)+";base64,#IMAGEDATA#\"‌​>")
```

and save it it give the Error:

```
Save Could not be completed
some character can not be mapped using "Cp1252" Character encodding.
```

please give me the solution, I want send image with mail.

Answer (score -1):

Try this it will really help you:

```
mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  subject.toString()); 
mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:"+ file));
```