# Recive image via mail without the file type extension

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mime

In the app i'm creating I would like to send an image via email, so I'm using the following code to do so:

```
send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name = textName.getText().toString();
            String phone = textPhone.getText().toString();
            String message = textMessage.getText().toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"my@email.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "You have a new email");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Name: "+ name + '\n' + 
                                             "Phone: " + phone + '\n' + 
                                             "Text" + message);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.rbz.jewlerysearchengine/" + imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]));
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(ContactUs.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

For some reason I receive the mail with the image file but without the file type extension,  what can be the reason?

Comment: Where do you receive the mail? If it is on a windows computer it might just be hidden.

Comment: @Burkhard I'm using Gmail

Comment: Also, what is the value of `imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]`?

Comment: @RajeshJAdvani that's the picture that was selected from the grid layout by the user

Comment: See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244472/how-add-image-in-email-body

Comment: No, I meant - what is the value of the string that this expression returns? Also, can you look at the email headers? Find the part the looks like `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=picture;`. What is the value of `filename` in the header?