# base64 not display in image tag for email in android

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I have one html to display image as base64 :

```html
    <html><body>hello<br/><img style='display:block; width:100px;height:50px;' id='base64image' src='data:image/png;base64,<!-base 64 string-->' /></body></html>
```

the result is this:

[image]

but when i use this in Email like this:

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{to});
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
email.setType("text/html");
String body = new String("<html><body>hello<br/><img style='display:block; width:100px;height:50px;' id='base64image' src='data:image/png;base64,<!-base 64 string-->' /></body></html>");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email,"Choose an Email client :"));
```

The result is like below:

[image]

image is not display in mail. is there something that I am missing here. is there any limit to pass the base64 data or something other issue is here?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, it's not possible to do this with Intents.
>
> The reason why for example bold text is displayed in the EditText and
>   not an Image is that StyleSplan is implementing Parcelable whereas
>   ImageSpan does not. So when the Intent.EXTRA_TEXT is retrieved in the
>   new Activity the ImageSpan will fail to unparcel and therefor not be
>   part of the style appended to the EditText.
>
> Using other methods where you don't pass the data with the Intent is
>   unfortunately not possible here as you're not in control of the
>   receiving Activity.

I search lot for this issue and i found a very good answer at this link :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7550813/1186689

It gives the answer and also clear all doubts.

Comment: Does that mean if one would implement Parcelable for the ImageSpan it should work? I don't really have the time now but just wondering. This limitation is very annoying

Comment: you dont have control on intent that called. how will you pass parcelable?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work but try using this

```
email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
```

insted of

```
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
```

Comment: thaks for your response . i will try that

Comment: I am sure it does not change anything.