# Send html content in mail body via intent in android

Tags: android

I want to send a mail via app.In the mail body the html contains multiple images and text.Note that I don't want images in the attachment.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: the answer Elenasys will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are trying to send images inserted in the html via email, unfortunately that´s not possible, you only can send the images attached to the email :(.

see this answer:
**[How to add an image in email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244472/how-to-add-an-image-in-email-body)**

**Update**: 
I think this library will do the job:

http://www.example-code.com/android/smtp_EmbedImage.asp