# How to get user gmail contacts and send Email from android phone

Tags: android

How to get the Gmail contacts data includes like first Name,Last-name B Day Email address Phone Number and the User Photo.How to send Email to a gmail contact from the android Phone.Using the Face Book SDK we can able to get the user contacts details but the Gmail is not come up with a SDK how to get these details.

Answer (score 1):

The class you're looking for is the ContactsContract. The [documentation is here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html)

Nested within ContactContract is a table of common data types, for instance, the contact photo:

java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo

Once you have the contact information you need, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585556/how-to-send-email-in-android) covers using an intent to send an email.