# How can I send an email from android application directly without showing the default email form of the device?

Tags: android, email

I am building a form that sends emails from an android application, I am using Intents to send the email, that is:

```
Intent sendIntent;
sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

My requirement is that I want the email to be sent immediately, currently the application is showing me installed email applications in device where I can recompose the email before sending, I want to send the mail directly without showing installed applications.

Thanks

Comment: See these solutions: [solution 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app/2033124#2033124) [solution 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-email-from-my-android-application) and [email with attachments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585556/how-to-send-email-in-android)

Comment: Solution 1 is good but there are two issues: How can I get the email and password saved on the echange server of my device, and second thing does it work for both secure and insecure mail servers? and what if I need to add attachments

Comment: if you check more answers in solution 1, you will find out the attachment code.

Comment: i have updated the answer for attachments.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, it worked fine, I didn't test the attachment code though, One more thing, how can I get the email and password saved on the exchange server of the device, is this possible?

Comment: It is working great, but any idea about the exchange server email and password saved on the device? Thanks again

Comment: Do you mean email address of any contact?

Comment: No, when you configure your device for sending mails, you actually give it a user name and password which the device saves and uses for future email sending and synchronizing,  my question is how to get these saved values?

Comment: use this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Comment: Try this also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556495/get-owners-email-address

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to get the owner email account, but not the password, I kept getting the error: "Caller uid 10085 is different than the authenticator's uid",Regards

Comment: thank u !! answer 1 was very helpful thank u :)
but don't forget to add internet permission and to tick all the added libraries in Order and Export

Comment: I don't want static password.. i want dynamic data  as the user has signed in to the device...how can I implement solution 1 with this requirement... as  username and password can vary from device to device

Comment: Checkout https://gist.github.com/gelldur/9c199654c91b13478979

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways

1) using SMTP [follow the link for details](http://javapapers.com/android/android-email-app-with-gmail-smtp-using-javamail/)

2) using Webservice( for example PHP script ) so there is a server side code and you hit that URL with param like ( name,subject etc) so basically PHP code send mail at the end and it's very easy to use .

Personally, I suggest you use Webservice

Answer (score 0):

From what I have been able to find people suggest you write your own mini email app within your app. The following link is to a person who did just that:

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android

Keep in mind to scroll through the bottom comments when you get stuck implementing certain parts. I hope that helps you from reinventing the wheel. :)

Comment: Link no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution

1) use JavaMail API

2) Implement  SMTP 
to send mail without showing default.email application.