# intent to share text to email clients (only email clients)

Tags: android

```
String value = text.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"test@test.test"});
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, value);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

this code runs, but it show a list of applications like notepad (and other notepad app), whatsapp (and several chat app).

I need a list of only email clients. I done a long search but the code is always same.

Comment: Checkout Share Builder https://gist.github.com/gelldur/9c199654c91b13478979

Answer (score 2):

try the following code with content type:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "some@email.address" });
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

Edit1: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264698/how-can-i-send-an-email-from-android-application-directly-without-showing-the-de) for sending email directly without opening the email client.

Comment: Better :-) Now I see: bump, crypto4all, drive, email, gmail, k-9 mail, nfc tapping huh? Can I create a complete form to send automatically an email? thanks

Comment: you can also try with `i.setType("message/rfc822");` this may remove non email client from list.. could not understand your comment.. do you want to send email without opening the email application?

Comment: sorry 4 my english :-( alternative of use of intents, create a form to send directly by email (without email client)