# Sending email from android app without using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am building an app that has an Activity where client enters his information and presses a button, something like "Place Order". I want my app to send an E-mail  with his information to my address after pressing this button. I don't need an Intent, since I don't really know if user set up an Email on his phone or not, so my best bet is to hardcode my Email into code (write my own client) so that e-mail will come from myself with his info. I've searched other threads and found that solutions where people added 3 JAR (mail.jar, additional.jar, activation.jar) and 2 classes GMailSender and JSSEProvider. However, I couldn't get it to work. I have a button with a method OnSend

```
public void onSend (View view) {
    try {
        GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("seidalins@gmail.com", "mypassword");
        sender.sendMail("This is Subject",
                "This is Body",
                "seidalins@gmail.com",
                "seidalins@gmail.com");
        Toast.makeText(this, "button ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

No Exception, I mean I have a Toast saying "button ok" however no email comes.

OR is there any other solutions? Can I, for example, use Parse.com to populate database with his info and then use Parse to send e-mail to me with info? Is it possible?

Comment: use this http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android

Comment: @Fahim tried it, however I got an exception and I can't understand why

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264698/how-can-i-send-an-email-from-android-application-directly-without-showing-the-de